# ng-model not working when value set using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, dialog

I have a bootstrap popup dialog with some form controls. each control binded using ng-model. to two of the textboxes in the dialog i'm setting the value using jquery when the dialog opens and the rest two are user editable. the two which are user editable for them ng-model is working fine. but for others its not. If i change the value by myself they work properly. but not when value is set using jQuery. I have to set the value using jquery. Struggling from past few days.
Any help will be appreciated.
Here is my code

```
<body ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<div class="container">

  <h3>Modal Example</h3>

  <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
  <div>
    <a href="#contactUser" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch Modal</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal -->


  <div id="contactUser" class="modal fade openDilog" role="dialog">
    <div id="emailform" class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>Contact User</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body ">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="subject">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="email" ng-model="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Subject" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="username">UserName:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="username" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter UserName" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="subject">Subject:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Enter Subject" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="message">Message:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" required ng-model="message" id="message" placeholder="Message Goes Here"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
              <button type="submit" ng-click="Contact()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Javascript

```
$('.openDilog').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[type="email"]').val('email@gmail.com');
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="username"]').val('username');
});

var app = angular.module('my-app', []);

    app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){

         $scope.Contact = function() {
      console.log($scope.email);
      console.log($scope.subject);
      console.log($scope.message);
      console.log($scope.username);
    }
    });
```

here is a fiddle i have created for the issue

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e4uteddu/7/)

Comment: why you not assign username,email directly in $scope instead of input?

Comment: actually i have a table of users and when a button for a particular user is clicked this dialog opens. The values are corresponding to the selected user. if it would have been for a single user i would have done it that way.

Comment: Create an array of users and use ng-repeat instead?
No reason to use Jquery at all. It is good practice to avoid JQuery in angular.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Working Plnkr](https://jsfiddle.net/gc2wpqbw/)

You can do this by accessing `scope` from outside controller.

**HTML:** Just add an `id` attribute in `HTML`. e.g-> `id='outer'`

```
<body ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="Ctrl" id='outer'>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.openDilog').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var scope = angular.element($("#outer")).scope();
    scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.email = 'email@gmail.com';
        scope.username = 'username';
    });

});
```

Hope that solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

can you init the values in angular scope ?

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', []);

    app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){

$scope.listUser = [
{email: "test1@test.com", username:"test1"},
{email: "test2@test.com", username:"test2"},
{email: "test3@test.com", username:"test3"},
{email: "test4@test.com", username:"test4"}
];
         $scope.Contact = function() {
      console.log($scope.email);
      console.log($scope.subject);
      console.log($scope.message);
      console.log($scope.username);
    }

    $scope.openPopin = function(username, email) {
      $scope.email = email;
      $scope.username = username;
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
<body ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<div class="container">

  <h3>Modal Example</h3>

  <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
  <div>
    <a href="#contactUser" ng-repeat="user in listUser" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="openPopin(user.username, user.email)">Launch Modal</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal -->


  <div id="contactUser" class="modal fade openDilog" role="dialog">
    <div id="emailform" class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>Contact User</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body ">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="subject">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="email" ng-model="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Subject" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="username">UserName:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="username" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter UserName" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="subject">Subject:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Enter Subject" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="message">Message:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" required ng-model="message" id="message" placeholder="Message Goes Here"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
              <button type="submit" ng-click="Contact()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

[this is my fiddle with ng-repeat](https://jsfiddle.net/b52ahv6d/)

Comment: actually i cant not do that because these values will wil coming based on the selected row from a table

Comment: can you give me a example ?

Comment: i have a list being fetched from database. and is displayed as table using ng-repeat so when the button corresponding to a particular row is clicked values fro that row are supposed to come in the controls.

Comment: I change my example with ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ui.bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) module which do all of the hard work that you trying to do for you